# A proof using the Argument Principle.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, residue-calculus

Here is the question I am trying to prove (I am very new to complex analysis):

Let $p(z)$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ and take $R > 0$ so large that the circle $\gamma(t) = R e^{it}, 0 \leq t \leq 2 \pi,$ encloses all the zeros of $p$ in its interior. Prove that $$\int_{\gamma} \frac{p'(z)}{p(z)}dz = 2 \pi n i.$$

Here is the Argument Principal Statement:

Let $f(z)$ be analytic inside and on a simple closed contour $C$ except for a finite number of poles inside $C,$  and suppose $f(z) \neq 0$ on $C.$ If $N_f$ and $P_f$ are respectively, the number of zeros (a zero of order $k$ being counted $k$ times) and poles (again with multiplicity) inside $C,$ then $$\int_{C} \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz = 2 \pi i (N_f  - P_f).$$

**My questions are:**

I am trying to see if the assumptions of the principle are satisfied in case of my problem or not so that I can solve the problem with it. First, the definition of a pole is:

An isolated singularity of $f(z)$ at $z = z_0$ is said to be a pole of $f(z)$ iff $\lim_{z\to z_0} f(z) = \infty.$

So, I am guessing that the given polynomial does not have a pole but I do not know how to justify this mathematically, **could anyone help me in showing this please?**

Also, I do not know why $f(z) \neq 0$ on $C$ in my case ( a polynomial of degree n), **could anyone explain this to me please?**

Comment: Why down voting?

Comment: You are asking very basic questions that have nothing to do, as such, with the argument principle. A polynomial is analytic everywhere, so has no singularities at all. The fundamental theorem of algebra tells us that $p$ has exactly $n$ roots, and since they are all in the 'interior' of $C$, clearly $p$ must be non zero on $C$.